# How to concatenate two bytes in CAPL?

Tags: concatenation, capl

I have been working on a CAPL code to display certain values from CAN signals on my Panel.
I am now stuck at a point, where I have to merge two bytes in order to proceed further with my code. I am getting an error 'operand types are incompatible'.
I am unable to find any possible formats to fix this issue.
My code is,

````
variables
{
float g_Temperature_17;
int firstByteValue_Temp_17;
int secondByteValue_Temp_17;
char firstByteTemp_17;
char secondByteTemp_17;
double temp_17;
}
on message *
{
if(this.id == 0x18FE5ECFx)
{
  if(this.byte(0) == 0x17)
  {
    firstByteValue_Temp_17 = this.byte(2); //picks up byte values in decimal
    secondByteValue_Temp_17 = this.byte(1);
    snprintf(firstByteTemp_17,elcount(firstByteTemp_17),"&d",firstByteValue_Temp_17); //decimal to hex
    snprintf(secondByteTemp_17,elcount(secondByteTemp_17),"&d",secondByteValue_Temp_17);      
    temp_17 = (secondByteTemp_17<<8) | (firstByteTemp_17); //cancatenate two bytes(ERORR here at '<<')
    g_Temperature_17 = (temp_17*0.03125)-273;
    sysSetVariableFloat(sysvar::R141::TyreTemp_0x17,g_Temperature_17);
  }```
````

Comment: Compiles for me. Which CANoe version are you using? Apart from that, this kind of calculation is something which CANoe does for you, when you set-up your DBC correctly. I.e. configure a signal in message `0x18FE5ECF`, describing which bits the signal uses and its factor and offset.

Comment: Thanks @MSpiller, I had a mismatching Message ID name with DBC file and CAPL message. Now I can easily use signal names and job is done. Great to figure it out, Thank you as always.